Generator bonded or floating neutral
Since I am using a NEMA 14-50 R 4 prong power cord connected to a 50 amp outlet on my generator should the generator neutral be bonded.  I have gotten different answers from various sources I have asked.  I believe it should be floating since the cord is connected to the main panel through the 50 amp power inlet box to a 50 amp breaker and the neutral and ground tied to the bars in the main panel.

What are you using as a transfer means? An interlock?

You have two separately derived systems. Your utility power and generator power, and both need the neutral and ground to be bonded at the first means of disconnect. Most likely that would be at the main panelboard in residential buildings.
It is not unusual for generators to be grounded, but it is only supplementary to the buildings ground following the single point of ground rule, and I have also seen the neutral and ground bonded at the generator. Even though I personally see no harm in it. It does not meet NEC Standards.
If the neutral and ground are currently bonded at the first means of disconnect then your neutral is not floating as long as it makes when you transfer power to your generator.
Hope this helps.
